# Can't pass an entity as an parameter to another action in the same controller in CakePHP 3.2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

While adding a new book into the DB I want to have separate actions for patching the request in a new entity and for saving that entity. The action for patching request into new entity returns this entity to another method.

The code is like this:

```
public function bookAdder($book = [])
    {
        if ($this->Books->save($book)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The book has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The book could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'add']);
            }
    }


    public function add()
    {
        $user_id = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id');
        $book = $this->Books->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $book = $this->Books->patchEntity($book, $this->request->data);
            $book->set(array('user_id' => "$user_id"));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'bookAdder', $book]);
        }
        $users = $this->Books->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('book', 'users'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['book']);
    }
```

While saving a test record, I am getting this error:

> Error: A route matching "/books/book-adder/{ "title": "cc", "writer":
>   "cc", "edition": "cc", "course": "cc", "description": "cc", "price":
>   2, "user_id": "1"}" could not be found.

[Error screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/554AV.png)

I also tried `public function bookAdder($book){ }`
 but still no success.

Is there any way to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Multiple Functions !**

> Are you doing some practice for making multiple functions ? That's
>   great if you make your function reusable and more readable.

But what you are doing here is adding some complexity for nothing. When you redirect to bookAdder function you would generate url something like this:

```
book-adder/%7B%0A%20%20%20%20"name"%3A%20"abc"%2C%0A%20%20%20%20"user_id"%3A%20"1"%0A%7D
```

And you are passing entity as function parameter. And obviously that routing error occur.

So you really don't need multiple function here at least for things you are doing.

Make it simple:

```
public function add()
{
    $user_id = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id');
    $book = $this->Books->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $book = $this->Books->patchEntity($book, $this->request->data);
        $book->set(array('user_id' => "$user_id"));
        if ($this->Books->save($book)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The book has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The book could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'add']);
        }
    }
    $users = $this->Books->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('book', 'users'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['book']);
}
```

If you really need entity from another function program flow should be something like this:

**makeEntity function:**

```
public function makeEntity($book = null,$requestData = []) {
    $book = $this->Books->patchEntity($book, $requestData);
    return $book;
}
```

**Add function:**

```
public function add()
{
    $user_id = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id');
    $book = $this->Books->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $book = $this->makeEntity($book, $this->request->data);
        $book->set(array('user_id' => "$user_id"));
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'bookAdder', $book]);
    }
    $users = $this->Books->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('book', 'users'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['book']);
}
```

And which doesn't make much differences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) But is it possible? I wish I somehow can get reference of the entity made in the add() function and then pass it to the bookAdder() function.

Comment: This is not possible this way and it is really bad practice as there is really no meaning on doing that..and never pass parameter that way..which will always generate error..If you really need that you can return entity from one function and get that from another function by calling the function..but never pass entity as parameter !

Comment: See updated answer if you really wish to get Entity from another function !

Comment: If you have that function in the controller, then it should better be protected or even private, as public functions are generally considered controller actions. @ShubhamArora If you need to separate logic for reuse, you should also consider whether it may be better suited in a component or the model layer.

Comment: Thanks @ManoharKhadka It really helped me. You nailed it completely :) I rewrote bookAdder() and now it works perfectly fine.